# ReactJS routing ambiguous route matching

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have looked at the training documentation about React routing for ambiguous matches and understand you can have static routes such as /about, /contact and then a match for /:user inside a switch.

What I am struggling with is, I have the need to have routes on the same level but using different components depending on the route,

**e.g:**

```
/devon        - RegionComponent
/privacy      - PageComponent
/dog-friendly - SearchResultsComponent
```

All of the routes I would have are in a database and therefore need to be dynamic.

How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

## install packages

npm install react-router-dom --save

## import this line

`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";`

## add this code in rander function

`<Router>
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/contact " component={contact } />

   </Router>`

Answer (score 0):

You must define at least 1st word of dynamic route. See below code

```
render((
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="user/*" component={UserComponent}/>
      <Route path="courses/*" component={CoursesComponent}/>
    </Route>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

In above example you can have any dynamic routes which can starts with **user/** or **courses/**

React router will redirect you to appropriate component based on your route.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have routes to exact the location use following

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={YourRootComponent} />
      <Route path="/devon" component={RegionComponent} />
      <Route path="/privacy" component={PageComponent} />
      <Route path="/dog-friendly" component={SearchResultsComponent} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Note: The 'exact' will ensure that it will match the exact '/' path. Otherwise if you do not use 'exact' for your root then it will match all the routes first with '/' and display your root component and will surpass the other routes. In case if you do not want to use 'exact', other alternative could be to write your root route i.e. `'<Route path="/" component={YourRootComponent} />'` at the very end of other routes.

As for dynamic routes you can always use `ES6's template literals` to attach dynamic strings in your route.